# SonarQube service not starting

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube5.3, sonarqube-ops

We are seeing below error while starting SonarQube service. Looks like there is a duplicate entry while registering Quality Profile but I am not sure on the table. Since the service is not started, we cannot verify it from web. Can someone please advise.

The issue occurred post creation of a new DB and copy of tables data from old DB. We are performing this to check new collation which is required for Sonar.

```
2016.04.26 15:41:53 INFO  web[o.s.s.s.RegisterDebtModel] Register technical debt model
2016.04.26 15:41:53 INFO  web[o.s.s.r.RegisterRules] Register rules
2016.04.26 15:41:58 INFO  web[o.s.s.q.RegisterQualityProfiles] Register quality profiles
2016.04.26 15:42:00 INFO  web[o.s.s.n.NotificationService] Notification service stopped
2016.04.26 15:42:00 ERROR web[o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/]] Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.sonar.server.platform.PlatformServletContextListener
 org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.TooManyResultsException: Expected one result (or null) to be returned by selectOne(), but found: 2
  at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectOne(DefaultSqlSession.java:70) ~[mybatis-3.2.7.jar:3.2.7]
  at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.execute(MapperMethod.java:68) ~[mybatis-3.2.7.jar:3.2.7]
  at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy.invoke(MapperProxy.java:52) ~[mybatis-3.2.7.jar:3.2.7]
  at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy34.selectDefaultProfile(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
  at org.sonar.db.qualityprofile.QualityProfileDao.selectDefaultProfile(QualityProfileDao.java:176) ~[sonar-db-5.3.jar:na]
  at org.sonar.server.qualityprofile.RegisterQualityProfiles.setDefault(RegisterQualityProfiles.java:161) ~[sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
  at org.sonar.server.qualityprofile.RegisterQualityProfiles.registerProfilesForLanguage(RegisterQualityProfiles.java:131) ~[sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
  at org.sonar.server.qualityprofile.RegisterQualityProfiles.start(RegisterQualityProfiles.java:95) ~[sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
  at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.invokeMethod(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:110) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
  at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.start(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:89) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
  at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$1.start(ComponentContainer.java:291) ~[sonar-core-5.3.jar:na]
  at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.start(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:84) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
  at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.start(AbstractBehavior.java:169) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
  at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored$RealComponentLifecycle.start(Stored.java:132) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
  at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.start(Stored.java:110) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
  at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.potentiallyStartAdapter(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1016) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
  at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.startAdapters(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1009) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
  at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.start(DefaultPicoContainer.java:767) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
  at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:131) ~[sonar-core-5.3.jar:na]
  at org.sonar.server.platform.platformlevel.PlatformLevel.start(PlatformLevel.java:84) ~[sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
  at org.sonar.server.platform.platformlevel.PlatformLevelStartup.access$001(PlatformLevelStartup.java:45) ~[sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
  at org.sonar.server.platform.platformlevel.PlatformLevelStartup$1.doPrivileged(PlatformLevelStartup.java:82) ~[sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
  at org.sonar.server.user.DoPrivileged.execute(DoPrivileged.java:45) ~[sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
  at org.sonar.server.platform.platformlevel.PlatformLevelStartup.start(PlatformLevelStartup.java:78) ~[sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
  at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.executeStartupTasks(Platform.java:197) ~[sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
  at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.doStart(Platform.java:114) ~[sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
  at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.doStart(Platform.java:99) ~[sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
  at org.sonar.server.platform.PlatformServletContextListener.contextInitialized(PlatformServletContextListener.java:43) ~[sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4720) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5154) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1399) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
```

Comment: From which version of SonarQube are you upgrading ? What are the versions of installed plugins before and after the upgrade ? Thanks

Comment: The server is running on version 5.3 . There is no version upgrade. We have a new DB where the collation is Latin1_General_CS_AS which is the requirement for Sonar. Our current DB has collation Latin1_General_CI_AS. Some of our builds are failing and we are trying to figure out if the collation is the issue. We created the new database with required collation and changed sonar properties. On start, it created tables. Now, we are trying to import data from old database. Basically, we did an "Insert into Select from" but seems this is not the right approach.

Comment: Could you give the results of "select * from rules_profiles where is_default=1" please ?

Comment: We had trucated all tables and restarted Sonar service post which it started properly.