# Sonarqube DB Copy Tool - where to get jar?

Tags: sonarqube, enterprise

I received trial Enterprise Licence and want to use DB Copy Tool. But in https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Sonar+DB+Copy+Tool no explanation where to get it. It's not in plugins/marketplace no results in google.
Maybe anyone knows where to get this jar? Maybe somewhere exists any guide?

Answer (score 3):

Since the Sonar DB Copy Tool is a commercial tool available to Enterprise Edition customers, you need to get in touch with your SonarSource contacts if you wish to obtain it.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is Web Service API, available since SonarQube 4.2.

You can access in

> {URL_Sonar}/api_documentation

Or you can use a [custom solution to data migration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37545872/sonar-data-migration-post-database-collation-change/57148722#57148722).